# Cubecart 5.2.12 in admin side order page in display product image

Tags: php

I am use cubecart 5.2.12 in this admin order index page.
index page in how to display product images.
check below image.
[image]

Comment: follow this link...may solve your problem,... 

http://www.cubecartforums.org/index.php?showtopic=10158

Comment: and please provide background code , so that every one can help...

Comment: if you have solved problem, please post solution in answer, otherwise provide code or error you are facing.